# Play a sound with VBA if an error is found

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have this code:

```
Option Explicit 

Private Declare Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" _ 
Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName _ 
As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long 

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 

Dim Cell            As Range 
Dim CheckRange      As Range 
Dim PlaySound       As Boolean 

Set CheckRange = Range("C:C") 
For Each Cell In CheckRange 
    If Cell.Value = "#N/A" Then 
        PlaySound = True 
    End If 
Next 
If PlaySound Then 
    Call sndPlaySound32("C:\windows\media\chord.wav", 1) 
End If      
End Sub
```

I am trying to get it so that if there is an error in column C, an audible sound is played, however it does not work, any ideas?

Comment: +1 for the idea, for future possible use)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need API for this

You can use `Beep` as well.

```
Sub Sample()
    Beep
End Sub
```

**Example**

**WAY 1**

This code will run if there is change anywhere in the sheet

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cell            As Range
    Dim CheckRange      As Range

    Set CheckRange = Range("C:C")

    For Each Cell In CheckRange
        If Cell.Text = "#N/A" Then
            Beep
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**WAY 2**

Alternative of above code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range

    For Each Cell In Columns(3)
        On Error Resume Next
        If CVErr(Cell) = CVErr(2042) Then
            Beep
            Exit For
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
End Sub
```

**Way 3**

If you want the to check Col C only if there is a manual change anywhere in Col C

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then
        For Each Cell In Columns(3)
            On Error Resume Next
            If CVErr(Cell) = CVErr(2042) Then
                Beep
                Exit For
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

**Way 4**

If you want the to check a particular cell if there is a manual change in that cell

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        If CVErr(Target) = CVErr(2042) Then
            Beep
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub
```

**Way 5**

Variation of Way 4

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Text = "#N/A" Then
            Beep
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP (Post Comments)**

> The active cell will be in column b, so it should check one right in column d – Sam Cousins 1 min ago

I guess you meant Col C and not Col D. You have to use `Worksheet_SelectionChange` for this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Offset(, 1).Text = "#N/A" Then
            Beep
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this. However, excel is checking for the string '#N/A' when I think an error is something else. Any clues?

Comment: Sid, what about **custom** sound?

Comment: @PeterL.: I will come back to you once I answer Sam's query :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout no problem, just wondering) `Beep` itself is a nice thing)

Comment: @SamCousins: Use Cell.text in my above code as :@Ripster suggested :)

Comment: Thank you for your help Siddharth, no an #N/A error will not occur if the user types anywhere beside Col C, however the code you have given me gives the same result as others, no matter when the cell is it will always beep, any idea why?

Comment: @SamCousins: Which code are you trying? I have give you 5 ways

Comment: I have tried 1 and 2, 3 4 and 5 are not quite what I require, however #1 and #2 are

Comment: @SamCousins: I have an idea. Type this line `Msgbox Cell.Address` after this line in Way 1 `If Cell.Text = "#N/A" Then` What do you get?

Comment: I get $C$4 in the messagebox

Comment: @SamCousins: What does `C4` have? any chance, i can see your workbook? If yes, then you may upload it in www.wikisend.com and share the link here?

Comment: @SamCousins: Cell `C4` in sheet `Spare` has `#N/A` and hence you are getting the beep. So it si working corrctly?

Comment: I think it needs to exclude previous #N/As to work correctly? Is that right?

Comment: @SamCousins: What exactly are you trying to do? My understanding of your question is that if Col C has #NA then there should be an audible sound. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sorry I should of made it more clear, it should just check 1 cell to the right of the active cell, does that make more sense?

Comment: @SamCousins: Which column are you checking the #NA in?

Comment: @SamCousins So the code finds #NA in say C4. Then what should be the next step?

Comment: It should beep, and then stop looking until the user is on the next row, and only checks that row for errors, and so on

Comment: @SamCousins: Oh so you want to check ActiveCell in Column C for #NA?

Comment: The active cell will be in column b, so it should check one right in column d

Comment: @SiddharthRout I see that Beep thing brought a lot of fun over there)))))

Comment: Thank you Sid, you have helped me greatly.

Answer (score 5):

Just Paste the below code and run and see if it works...

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" _
Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName _
As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim PlaySound As Boolean

    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        For Each Cell In Target
            If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cell.Value) Then
                PlaySound = True
            End If
        Next

        If PlaySound Then
            Call sndPlaySound32("C:\windows\media\chord.wav", 1)
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cell.Value)` is the approach I would use to specifically find an #NA error.

Answer (score 1):

Change Cell.Value to Cell.Text

If there is a formula error the cells value will be something along the lines of Error 2042 but your if statement is looking for the text "#N/A"

I also suggest using only the used range instead of the entire column since this will decrease the time it takes to run.

You can also exit the for immediately if an error is found.

Using Beep will not allow you to play any sound but it will make an audible sound and does not require an API call or the computer to have the specified audio file.

-EDIT-
I just tested the code below and it appears to work correctly for me.

-EDIT2-
Corrected code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim CheckRange As Range

    Set CheckRange = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 3))
    For Each Cell In CheckRange
        If Cell.Text = "#N/A" Then
            Beep
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

-EDIT3-
Working copy of your original post

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" _
                                        Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName _
                                                               As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim CheckRange As Range
    Dim PlaySound As Boolean

    Set CheckRange = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 3))
    For Each Cell In CheckRange
        If Cell.Text = "#N/A" Then
            PlaySound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If PlaySound Then
        Call sndPlaySound32("C:\windows\media\chord.wav", 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This results in the sound being played even if the value is not an error, any ideas?

Comment: When scanning it results in no sound being played at all for neither error or non-error. hmm

Comment: I just realized you are only doing this for a single worksheet. My code was for a workbook. I corrected it to work for a specific worksheet.

Comment: Now I am having the same issue as the others, the script will beep error or not, I appreciate your help

Comment: The code will only run for the sheet it is added to. Are you 100% sure the code has been added to the correct sheet and you are testing for errors on the same sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace with `If PlaySound = True Then`

Answer (score 0):

I think your If statement which checks the value of PlaySound should be inside your For loop. The way you have it written it will only make a noise if the last cell in CheckRange = "#N/A" because PlaySound will hold the last value assigned to it from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is supported by both 32-bit and 64-bit systems:

```
#If Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" _
                 Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName _
                        As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" _
                  Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName _
                         As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim PlaySound As Boolean

    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        For Each Cell In Target
           If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cell.Value) Then
               PlaySound = True
           End If
        Next
        If PlaySound Then
            Call sndPlaySound32("C:\windows\media\chord.wav", 1)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```