# Need Beep sound when value of Cell(W10) >= value of Cell(R10), this is for entire column of W and R

Tags: excel, vba

Need Beep sound when value of Cell(R10) >= value of Cell(W10), this is for entire column of R and W.

Note that "R10 to R31" cell has data streaming online (not fed manually) and Cell W10 to W31 has formula: `=S10*70%+(S10)`

So far I have got this but does not seem to work `=IF(R10>W10,StopCounter(),"")`

```
Function StopTrigger(RngMeasure As Range)

Public BlnAboveHundred As Boolean
```

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
Dim StopTrigger As Range
Dim CurrentMeasure As Range
'Dim RngCounter As Range

Set StopTrigger = Range("W10:W31")
Set CurrentMeasure = Range("B10:B31")
'Set RngCounter = Range("C9")

If Not (Intersect(Target, StopTrigger) Is Nothing) Then
    If CurrentMeasure.Value > W10 Then
        If BlnAboveHundred = False Then
            RngCounter.Value = RngCounter.Value + 1
            BlnAboveHundred = True
        End If
    Else
        BlnAboveHundred = False
    End If
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: `If RngMeasure.Value < Then` is missing the right-hand side of the comparison, for starters. And when you call the function you are not passing any arguments, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962631/play-a-sound-with-vba-if-an-error-is-found

Comment: @BigBen, can we create a function for this so i Can call it from a cell